# Disk usage "shown" to be extremely high on NFS share

Tags: linux, nfs, file-sharing

I have an NFS share between two machines. The share is showing unusually large usage whereas it has only 4-5 files:

It's "mounted" on server, shared on 999.99.999.99:

```
root@server [~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             446G   13G  410G   4% /
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   77M  19% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
999.99.999.99:/srv/els1-share
                      220G   10G  199G   5% /srv/els1-share
```

File listing:

```
root@server [~]# ls -laR /srv/els1-share/
/srv/els1-share/:
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 21 23:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 15 06:53 ..
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Oct 16 05:55 .my.cnf.12877
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Oct 16 05:55 .mysql.12877
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 21 10:16 ROOT
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 15 06:55 test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 16 05:34 test3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 16 05:54 test4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 21 23:53 test5

/srv/els1-share/ROOT:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 21 10:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 21 23:53 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` shows usage on the entire volume, not just the slice that is being shared. Check the disk usage on the server itself.

Comment: Ahh... so its showing for the entire volume that '/' is on (on the sharing server)... interesting..! thanks for the insight...